# Mel Expression Syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, maya, mel

i don't normally script in `MEL` as my knowledge on it is very limited. 
I have made a expression however it keeps coming back with

```
// Error: Line 7.1: Syntax error //
```

Here is the expression:

```
if (global_IkFk_Ctr.L_Arm == 0) {
    l_Bn_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX == l_Ik_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX;
    l_Bn_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX == l_Ik_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX;
}

else (global_IkFk_Ctr.L_Arm == 1) {
    l_Bn_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX == l_Fk_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX;
    l_Bn_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX = l_Fk_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX;
}
```

Comment: I notice that is the only line with 1 equal character.

Comment: Yes sorry, i had had the expression with 1 equal character (apart from the condition) but that came back with a syntax error too so i tried putting a double equal character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` has a condition (`global_IkFk_Ctr.L_Arm == 1`), which means it needs to be an `else if`.

Also, `==` is used for comparison, but you're trying to use it for assignment. Assignment should be `=`.

```
if (global_IkFk_Ctr.L_Arm == 0){
    l_Bn_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX = l_Ik_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX;
    l_Bn_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX = l_Ik_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX;
}
else if (global_IkFk_Ctr.L_Arm == 1){
    l_Bn_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX = l_Fk_ShoulderJnt_01.scaleX;
    l_Bn_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX = l_Fk_ElbowJnt_01.scaleX;
}
```